# Use combo box in update query

Tags: database, ms-access, combobox

I have an update query that I would like to, if possible, use a combo box selection.  Example, form opens, select project, click update button that open the update query and the value from the form is is used in the update query.

Here is my update:

> UPDATE tblExport SET tblExport.PROJECT =
>   [Forms]![frmProjects]![Project].[AfterUpdate], tblExport.QUANTITY =
>   "1", tblExport.[ROOM NO] = [Forms]![frmProjects]![Room].[AfterUpdate],
>   tblExport.[Activity Revision] = "000", tblExport.MB = "M",
>   tblExport.PlaceHolder = "D";

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Ronie. Please post any relevant sample data and code. Have a look at these guidelines for crafting a good question: [Ask Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have it figured out now, but thank you for the opportunity to ask a question.

Comment: Great. Why don't you post the answer. It is perfectly acceptable to answer your own questions and it may help someone else in the future. [Also remember to accept your own answer by clicking on the greyed out check mark after it has been posted] Cheers!